# DHCP/DNS/Windows server 2008 / w7 / xp internet issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, windows-xp, vmware-vsphere

Title might be weird but I wanted to include all the factors involved.

I have a windows server 2008 r2 in a virtual network which has 2 networkadapters
The settings are the following

```
Adapter 1 (connected to the internet)
IP 192.168.27.40
SubnetMask 255.255.255.0
Gateway 192.168.27.1
DNS 192.168.200.14
```

and

```
Adapter 2 (used for passing dhcp to the clients and connected with Adapter 1 via NAT (RRAS)
IP 10.0.0.1
Subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: empty
DNS: 127.0.0.1
```

With these settings I was able to connect to the domain called `my.domain`.
I had internet at this point. Now the next I did was just shutting down the clients which I just added to the domain network.

I left for that day leaving the server on, and both clients off.
I joined today again and I have the server connected with adapter 1 to the internet, and using adapter 2 to spread around DHCP without any problem.

However, I cannot connect to the internet on the clients anymore. When I troubleshoot the issue it tells me: `The remote device or resource won't accept the connection`

This cannot be a firewall issue because the firewalls are OFF on both machines.

What can I do now? I'm clueless. If you need more information I'll be glad to add it.

EDIT:
The W7 has obtained these details:

```
IP: 10.0.0.22
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default gateway 10.0.0.1
DHCP Server 10.0.0.1
DNS Servers 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Is this also a domain controller?

Comment: yes, is this an issue?

Comment: Yes. Read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/08/17/multihomed-dcs-with-dns-rras-and-or-pppoe-adapters.aspx

Comment: Adding a second server now and configuring it as DC. Will check back later when I finish that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comment by Pauska: `Yes. Read this: msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/08/17/… – pauska 4 hours ago`

This was the problem. You cannot use NAT on a server which runs DHCP and a domain controller.

I've fixed this issue by seperating DHCP and NAT to its own server.
So I changed the "all-in-one" server to 1 server with DHCP and NAT into the domain which was created by the other server. The second server uses Active Directory Domain Services now.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Disable DNS registration for the external network card (in the advanced TCP/IP settings), so that you won't get the external IP registered for the internal hostname. Client's can't talk to the external IP of the server when they want to contact the server.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution for this issue.

Comment: @Robuust I take it that you have verified that your domain controller is not registered in your AD DNS zone with two different IP addresses?

Comment: I've found out that it won't work when DC + AD + DHCP + RRAS is added on 1 server. I separated both and now it works like a charm. DNS points to the DC/DNS Server now.